# SQL Finding Multiple Values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with fields named SVCode and LocationCode. I want to be able to focus on one all of the SVCodes listed in the column and check to see if their LocationCode is different.

Example:

```
LocationCode:         

107654403      
107654403    
107653802   
107653802   
107656502  
126515001  
128030852  
126515001
```

---

```
SVCode:  

STN10  
STN10  
STN10  
STN10  
STN10  
STN10  
GIN04      
GIN04  
GIN04
```

Each row matches up. LocationCode 107654403 with STN10 and so forth.

I want to basically create a new column called MultipleLocations and if a SVCode has more than one distinct Location code then set the MultipleLocation column = 1 else 0

Any help on doing so?

Comment: Are `LocationCode` and `SVCode` columns in *different* tables?  If so, how do you know which one corresponds with which?  Also, can you provide an example of what the output should be for your sample data above?

Comment: I was modifying an existing database to add a new multiplelocations column in. I have two tables, one named dbo.IndxServ and one named dbo.Service. Assuming i need to inner join IndxServ and Service on the SVCode (they both have it). dbo.IndxServ has Svcode, Description and the MultipleLocation column in it, but it is all set 0 since i havent modified anything yet. Dbo.Service has the LocationCode and the SVCode in it as well.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show your tables structure, some of your data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to identify those with multiple Locations:

```
SELECT SVCode
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LocationCode, SVCode
      FROM Table
      )sub
GROUP BY SVCode
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking some liberties with your column names, but

```
SELECT l.*, s.*, IF(COUNT(s.id) > 1,1,0) AS multipleLocation FROM LocationCode l
INNER JOIN SVCode s ON s.locationCodeId = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  distinct SVCode 
from Table1 t1
where exist
(select LocationCode from table1 where t1.SVCode  = SVCode and 
 LocationCode != t1.LocationCode );
```

this will give you list of all SVcode with multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
UPDATE t1
SET MultipleLocation = 1
WHERE SVCode IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SVCode FROM t1
    WHERE COUNT(SVCode) > 1
    GROUP BY SVCode
)
```

Good luck.